# How to collapse jQuery accordion menu consisting of div's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, accordion

I have seen many similar questions but still haven't found a solution to my problem.

I have made an accordion menu with duplicated jQuery code for every item in the menu. I was wondering if there isn't a more effective way with less jQuery code.

*Preferably no changes to the HTML markup please*

```
    $('.what-we-do-toggle1').click(function() {
        $('.what-we-do-text1').animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
        $('.what-we-do-text2').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text3').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text4').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text5').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text6').slideUp(200);
    });    
    $('.what-we-do-toggle2').click(function() {
        $('.what-we-do-text2').animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
        $('.what-we-do-text1').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text3').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text4').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text5').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text6').slideUp(200);
    });    
    $('.what-we-do-toggle3').click(function() {
        $('.what-we-do-text3').animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
        $('.what-we-do-text1').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text2').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text4').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text5').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text6').slideUp(200);
    });    
    $('.what-we-do-toggle4').click(function() {
        $('.what-we-do-text4').animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
        $('.what-we-do-text1').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text2').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text3').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text5').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text6').slideUp(200);
    });    
    $('.what-we-do-toggle5').click(function() {
        $('.what-we-do-text5').animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
        $('.what-we-do-text1').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text2').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text3').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text4').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text6').slideUp(200);
    });    
    $('.what-we-do-toggle6').click(function() {
        $('.what-we-do-text6').animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
        $('.what-we-do-text1').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text2').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text3').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text4').slideUp(200);
        $('.what-we-do-text5').slideUp(200);
    });
```

http://codepen.io/berry807/pen/KdGeVG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing markup

```
$('#what-we-do .row > div').click(function() {
    $('#what-we-do .row > div p').stop().slideUp(); // slide all up
    $(this).find('p').stop().slideToggle(); // slide this one down
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mezKBB

Comment: Your code does not toggle an opened item, check my script without need of changing html

Comment: Yes that is better nice use of stop function i like it! Nice and clean, better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#what-we-do .row > div').on('click', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $content = $this.children('p');
        if(!$this.hasClass('toggled'){
            $('#what-we-do .row > .toggled > p').slideUp();
            $('#what-we-do .row > .toggled').removeClass('toggled');

            $this.addClass('toggled');
            $content.slideDown();

        }else{
            $this.removeClass('toggled');
            $content.slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Please note I have not tested it but it should work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Without chaning the html-structure:

```
   $('#what-we-do .container .row div').on('click', function() {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        $(this).find($('.what-we-do-text' + i)).animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
      } 
   });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyJvEV

Comment: Doesn't this loop through all items and not the specific clicked item?

Comment: No, since are using .find() within $(this)-element

Comment: No need to loop, you can use a wildcard `$('[class*="what-we-do-text"]')` which is just as slow, but in any case that element is always the only `<p>`